# Hadoop mapreduce custom writable static context

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, writable

I'm working on an university homework and we have to use hadoop mapreduce for it. I'm trying to create a new custom writable as I want to output key-value pairs as (key, (doc_name, 1)).

```
public class Detector {

    private static final Path TEMP_PATH = new Path("temp");
    private static final String LENGTH = "gramLength";
    private static final String THRESHOLD = "threshold";


    public class Custom implements Writable {

        private Text document;
        private IntWritable count;

        public Custom(){
            setDocument("");
            setCount(0);
        }

        public Custom(String document, int count) {
            setDocument(document);
            setCount(count);
        }

        @Override
        public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            document.readFields(in);
            count.readFields(in);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
            document.write(out);
            count.write(out);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count.get();
        }

        public void setCount(int count) {
            this.count = new IntWritable(count);
        }

        public String getDocument() {
            return document.toString();
        }

        public void setDocument(String document) {
            this.document = new Text(document);
        }

    }

    public static class NGramMapper extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
        private int gramLength;
        private Pattern space_pattern=Pattern.compile("[ ]");
        private StringBuilder gramBuilder= new StringBuilder();

        @Override
        protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,      InterruptedException{
            gramLength=context.getConfiguration().getInt(LENGTH, 0);
        }

        public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String[] tokens=space_pattern.split(value.toString());
            for(int i=0;i<tokens.length;i++){
                gramBuilder.setLength(0);
                if(i+gramLength<=tokens.length){
                    for(int j=i;j<i+gramLength;j++){
                        gramBuilder.append(tokens[j]);
                        gramBuilder.append(" ");
                    }
                    context.write(new Text(gramBuilder.toString()), key);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static class OutputReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Custom> {

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            for (Text val : values) {
                context.write(key,new Custom(val.toString(),1));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        conf.setInt(LENGTH, Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
        conf.setInt(THRESHOLD, Integer.parseInt(args[1]));

        // Setup first MapReduce phase
        Job job1 = Job.getInstance(conf, "WordOrder-first");
        job1.setJarByClass(Detector.class);
        job1.setMapperClass(NGramMapper.class);
        job1.setReducerClass(OutputReducer.class);
        job1.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job1.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job1.setOutputValueClass(Custom.class);
        job1.setInputFormatClass(WholeFileInputFormat.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job1, new Path(args[2]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, new Path(args[3]));

        boolean status1 = job1.waitForCompletion(true);
        if (!status1) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile the code to a class file i get this error:

```
Detector.java:147: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
context.write(key,new Custom(val.toString(),1));
```

I followed differents tutorials about custom writable and my solution is the same as the others. Any suggestion?

Comment: Writing a custom writable is overkill. Try using Avro: https://avro.apache.org

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Static fields and methods are shared with all instances. They are for values which are specific to the class and not a specific instance. Stay out of them as much as possible.

To solve your problem, you need to instantiate an instance (create an object) of your class so the run-time can reserve memory for the instance; or change the part you are accessing it to have `static` access (**not recommended!**).

The keyword `this` is for referencing something that's indeed an instance (hence the *this* thing) and not something that's `static`, which in that case should be referenced by the class name instead. You are using it in a *static* context which is not allowed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Which class do you mean I need to create an instance? I'm creating an instance of Custom inside the Reducer by "context.write(key,new Custom(val.toString(),1));"

Comment: This is absolutely wrong. The class `Custom` needs to be defined as static, otherwise you can't create an instance of it without instantiating a `Detector` first. There is no field access involved.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut I answered in "general terms", hence the second and third paragraph. `this` is not explicitly used but when creating a new instance of `Custom`, which is not `static` as you point out, and used by all other `static` classes